# Adding group to as Site Administrator using CSOM

Tags: client-object-model

Is it possible to a add an existing group as SharePoint site collection administrator using CSOM(Client Side Object Model)? Please share the code for doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would try sticking an AD group in the example here..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mimorr/archive/2014/01/22/adding-site-collection-admin-in-csom-in-a-sharepoint-2013-app.aspx